# How to create a custom Shaped UIView?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios8, mask, cashapelayer

I want to create a UIView in Star, Pentagon, Hexagon, and Other custom Shapes.

I want to draw inside that custom shapes.

I've created a bezierPath and trying to mask the UIView to it.
but it doesn't work

```
CGFloat x=48;
CGFloat y=306;
oval2Path  = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[oval2Path moveToPoint: CGPointMake(x+340, y+427.5)];
[oval2Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(x+476.95, y+523.2)];
[oval2Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(x+424.64, y+678.05)];
[oval2Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(x+255.36, y+678.05)];
[oval2Path addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(x+203.05, y+523.2)];     [oval2Path closePath];
CAShapeLayer *mask = [CAShapeLayer layer];
mask.path = oval2Path.CGPath;
FinalAlgView *myView=[[FinalAlgView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,800,800)];
myView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
myView.layer.mask = mask;

[self.view bringSubviewToFront:drawShape];

[self.view addSubview:myView];
```

**IS there anyway to create UIView as custom Shapes**

Comment: are you asking if there is any way to have a custom frame in a UIView, if you can draw a shape in a UIView, or something else?  Im confused by the phrasing of the question mixed with the code example

Comment: @mattyice Thanks for your reply!! Is there any way to have custom frame to UIView??